# $X$ and $Y$ dependent when $X-E[X]=\alpha(Y-E[Y])$ - why?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expectation, independence

I have read in a book that $X$ and $Y$ are linearly dependent iff:
$$X-E_{\theta}[X]=\alpha(\theta)(Y-E_{\theta}[Y])$$
(for some $\alpha(\theta)$)

I was trying to understand where it comes from but I could not figure it out. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: A doubt. IS $\alpha$ a fixed quantity? Probably not, as take any 2 different distributions and X and Y from them; the expectations remain same, but X and Y can be anything, so $\alpha$ varies widely. For independence, pertaining to the general definition, there must be something else mentioned about X, Y, or $\alpha$

Comment: Ah, sorry, I put "independent", rather than "dependent". Also, $\alpha$ is a function of $\theta$. Editted now.

Comment: This means $X $ is an affine function of $Y $ which gives dependence.

Comment: @Ian Could you tell me how it works?

Comment: More precisely, why do we have expectations in the formula?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X,Y$ are linearly dependent. This means $Y=aX+b$ for some fixed $a,b$. Then $E[Y]=aE[X]+b$. Subtract this from the first equation to get $(Y-E[Y])=a(X-E[X])$. Now let $\alpha=1/a$.

Otherwise, suppose $X-E[X]=\alpha(Y-E[Y])$. Then $X=\alpha Y+(E[X]-\alpha E[Y])$, which is of the form $X=aY+b$, so $X,Y$ are linearly dependent.